# The WP post editor is blank

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problems with wordpress and I don't know if there's anything that has been deconfigured by itself, but since a couple of hours ago, I open any WP post in the editor and what I see is a blank screen although there is text there that can only be seen when selected with the mouse and it doesn't matter if they are published posts or drafts, the problem is the same.

I have cleared the cache in the hope that everything will be fixed but no, the problem persists. I have no idea what this is about and I would appreciate it if you guys who have the knowledge could please help me with this issue. Attached are two screenshots that explain the problem

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am not a programmer, so I appreciate it if you can explain me in a language that an ordinary person can easily understand. Thanks again.

P.S. 2: Most of the plugins that look outdated in the images have already been updated.

[IMG 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKWID.jpg)
[IMG 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2xTG.jpg)

Comment: Did you try using a different browser? Is the WP updated to the newest version?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. In case anyone is interested, the classic editor plugin was interfering. I removed it and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED. In case anyone is interested, the classic editor plugin was interfering. I removed it and everything is back to normal.